# Aggregate with a Composite Key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate some data and group it by Time Intervals as well as maintaining a sub-category, if you will. I want to be able to chart this data out so that I will have multiple different Lines corresponding to each Office that was called. The X axis will be the Time Intervals and the Y axis would be the Average Ring Time.

My data looks like this:

```
 Calls: [{
    created: ISODate(xyxyx), 
    officeCalled: 'ABC Office', 
    answeredAt: ISODate(xyxyx)
    },
    {
    created: ISODate(xyxyx), 
    officeCalled: 'Office 2', 
    answeredAt: ISODate(xyxyx)
    },
    {
    created: ISODate(xyxyx), 
    officeCalled: 'Office 3', 
    answeredAt: ISODate(xyxyx)
    }];
```

My goal is to get my calls grouped by Time Intervals (30 Minutes/1 Hour/1 Day) AND by the Office Called. So when my aggregate completes, I'm looking for data like this:

```
[{"_id":TimeInterval1,"calls":[{"office":"ABC Office","ringTime":30720},
            {"office":"Office2","ringTime":3070}]}, 
 {"_id":TimeInterval2,"calls":[{"office":"Office1","ringTime":1125},
            {"office":"ABC Office","ringTime":15856}]}]
```

I have been poking around for the past few hours and I was able to aggregate my data, but I haven't figured out how to group it properly so that I have each time interval along with the office data. Here is my latest code:

```
Call.aggregate([
{$match: {
    $and: [
        {created: {$exists: 1}}, 
        {answeredAt: {$exists: 1}}]}},
{$project: {    created: 1, 
            officeCalled: 1, 
        answeredAt: 1,  
        timeToAns: {$subtract: ["$answeredAt", "$created"]}}},

{$group: {_id: {"day": {"$dayOfYear": "$created"},

        "hour": {
            "$subtract": [
                {"$hour" : "$created"}, 
                {"$mod": [ {"$hour": "$created"}, 2]}
                ]
        }, 
                "officeCalled": "$officeCalled"

 }, 
    avgRingTime: {$avg: '$timeToAns'}, 
    total: {$sum: 1}}},

{"$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.day", 
        "calls": {
            "$push": {
                "office": "$_id.officeCalled", 
                "ringTime": "$avgRingTime"

            }, 

        }
    }}, 
 {$sort: {_id: 1}}


]).exec(function(err, results) {
    //My results look like this

     [{"_id":118,"calls":[{"office":"ABC Office","ringTime":30720}, 
       {"office":"Office 2","ringTime":31384.5},
       {"office":"Office 3","ringTime":7686.066666666667},...];

      });
```

This just doesn't quite get it...I get my data but it's broken down by Day only. Not my 2 hour time interval that I was shooting for. Let me know if I'm doing this all wrong, please --- I am VERY NEW to aggregation so your help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need to do is include the both parts of the `_id` value your want in the final group. No idea why you thought to only reference a single field.

Also "loose the `$project`" as it is just wasted cycles and processing, when you can just use directly in `$group` on the first try:

```js
Call.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": {
            "created": { "$exists": 1 },
            "answeredAt": { "$exists": 1 }
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "day": {"$dayOfYear": "$created"},
                "hour": {
                    "$subtract": [
                        {"$hour" : "$created"}, 
                        {"$mod": [ {"$hour": "$created"}, 2]}
                    ]
                }, 
                "officeCalled": "$officeCalled"

            }, 
            "avgRingTime": { 
                "$avg": { "$subtract": [ "$answeredAt", "$created" ] }
            }, 
            "total": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { 
                "day": "$_id.day",
                "hour": "$_id.hour"
            }, 
            "calls": {
                "$push": {
                    "office": "$_id.officeCalled", 
                    "ringTime": "$avgRingTime"
                }, 
            },
            "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
        }},
        { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
    ]
).exec(function(err, results) {

});
```

Also note the complete omission of `$and`. This is not needed as **all** MongoDB query arguments are already "AND" conditions anyway, unless specifically stated otherwise. Just stick to what is simple. It's meant to be simple.

Comment: Thank you, mate!

You are correct...it's simple and I think I always expect it to be more complex so I appreciate your help.

Cheers!